# .htaccess redirect for complex url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an website with the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^declinare/([^/]+)/? declinare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^conjugare/([^/]+)/? conjugare.php?cuvant=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ definitie.php?forma=$1&cuvant=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ definitie.php?forma=$1&cuvant=$2&pagina=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toatecuvintele\.ro$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.toatecuvintele\.ro$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.toatecuvintele\.ro\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toatecuvintele.ro$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.toatecuvintele\.ro\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^37\.156\.32\.57
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.toatecuvintele.ro/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything works fine except for one thing:
http://toatecuvintele.ro/cuvant/test does not redirect automatically to http://www.toatecuvintele.ro/cuvant/test

How can I do to redirect everything withc is Non WWW to www?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toatecuvintele\.ro$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.toatecuvintele.ro/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Does it matter the position? I ask because, I usually have 20-30 concurrent users on the site and I don't want them to feel anything.

Comment: No, that can be the last one, because it's only before the first page, and only one time for each "bad" user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^toatecuvintele\.ro$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.toatecuvintele\.ro$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.toatecuvintele.ro$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have this rule in htaccess. Look above.